# Dose Hyperscale (Citus) support ST_AsGeoBuf function?

Tags: azure, postgis

My problem:

I use postgres to execute sql, my sql use PostGis **ST_AsGeoBuf()** function, but as I know a lot of distributed cluster don't support this function. I would like to know if **Hyperscale (Citus)**  support this func?

What I have already tried:

I have search some cluster like greemplum, redshift. both are not supported:

`ST_AsGeoBuf()` func.

```
SELECT(
catetitle,
count(1),
public.ST_AsGeoBuf(
    feature,
    'geom'
)
)
```

Comment: azure platform.